# Siunitx adding the \cdot and \chemfig to get extra top space in a tabular

Tags: tables, siunitx, chemfig

i am having a problem compiling, i get an error of missing $ and { also } when i use \si....... [siunitx package] 
----> I tried the \sisetup... but it gives me an error, may be it has conflicts with other packages
Thanks

```
\documentclass[french,12pt,oneside,openright]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{babel} %langue francaise
\usepackage{graphicx,xcolor} %insertion d'images
\usepackage{titlesec}
\graphicspath{{Annexes/images/}} 
\usepackage{lipsum} 
%\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\usepackage[sonny]{fncychap}
\usepackage{usnomencl}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{titlesec, blindtext, color}
\definecolor{gray75}{gray}{0.75}
\newcommand{\hsp}{\hspace{20pt}}
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\Huge\bfseries}{\thechapter\hsp\textcolor{gray75}{|}\hsp}{0pt}{\Huge\bfseries}
\usepackage{multirow,array}
%\usepackage{longtable}%pour la liste des symbole en format tableau
%\usepackage{SIstyle} %Pour les unités dans la liste des symboles
%\usepackage{SIunits}
\usepackage{siunitx}
%\sisetup{inter-unit-product=\cdot}
\usepackage{tocloft} 
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\renewcommand*\printatom[1]{\ensuremath{\mathsf{#1}}}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{hyperref} 
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,positioning}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage{datetime}
\newdate{date}{xx}{xx}{xxxx}
\date{}
\usepackage{vmargin}
\setmarginsrb           { 1.5in}  % left margin
                        { 0.6in}  % top margin
                        { 1.0in}  % right margin
                        { 0.8in}  % bottom margin
                        {  20pt}  % head height
                        {0.25in}  % head sep
                        {   9pt}  % foot height
                        { 0.3in}  % foot sep
\raggedbottom
\aliaspagestyle{part}{empty}
\renewcommand{\printpartname}{}
\renewcommand{\partnamenum}{}
\renewcommand{\printpartnum}{}
\usepackage{booktabs}
    \begin{document}
        \begin{tabular}{l|c}
    \addlinespace        
    Structure& {\scriptsize\chemfig{O=[:-30]
            *6(-(-{\textit{t}-Bu})=N-N=(-{S\scriptsize{-}Me})-N(-{NH_2})-)}} \\\hline
    \addlinespace
            Masse molaire \si[inter-unit-product = \ensuremath{{}\cdot{}}] {\gram\cdot\per\mol} & 214.3\\\hline
            pKa& 1.0\\\hline
                \si{\gram\per\mol}
            \end{tabular}
        \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It is better to ask only one question per post, especially when they are not related as your questions are here. The answer to your first question is do not use `\cdot` in the argument to `\si`. Please produce a minimal example that includes `\documentclass{}`, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}` to help the users here to help you! :-) Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using `booktabs`. For the centered dot to denote product of units, just add

```
\sisetup{inter-unit-product=\cdot}
```

to your document preamble. For a text hyphen in a chemical formula, use `\text{-}`. You can incorporate it inside `\textit` for `t-Bu`.

```
\documentclass[french,12pt,oneside,openright]{memoir}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\sisetup{inter-unit-product=\cdot}

\renewcommand*\printatom[1]{\ensuremath{\mathsf{#1}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{lS[table-format=3.1]}
\toprule
\addlinespace
Structure& {\scriptsize\chemfig{O=[:-30]
*6(-(-{\textit{t-}Bu})=N-N=(-{S\text{-}Me})-N(-{NH_2})-)}} \\
\addlinespace
\midrule
Masse molaire \si{\gram\per\mol} & 214.3\\
pKa& 1.0\\
\si{\gram\per\mol}\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: can you please check my packages i guess siunitx is incompatible with some.

Comment: @Hamza.w I copied your preamble into my example and found nothing strange.

Comment: Uncomment the sisetup and try again , when i use it i get a math error $ is missing

Comment: @Hamza.w Sorry, no error. Note that I removed the `[inter-unit-product = \ensuremath{{}\cdot{}}]` option in the table (which is useless and wrong).

Comment: @egreg According to section 5.12 of the `siunitx` manual, it should actually be `inter-unit-product = \ensuremath{{}\cdot{}}`, as Hamza.w has done.